# How do I widen these Picker controls and align them on the right?

Tags: macos, xaml, xamarin.forms, picker

I have lots of questions in my head and I realise there are better ways that much of what you will see can be done. All with time as I learn.

In this particular instance I have created a `Frame` element with some controls:

```
    <Frame Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="Black" Margin="10">
        <StackLayout Spacing="10" >
            <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="DarkSalmon" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Report Settings"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <Label Text="Starting month:"/>
            <Picker Title="Select month">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>January</x:String>
                        <x:String>February</x:String>
                        <x:String>March</x:String>
                        <x:String>April</x:String>
                        <x:String>May</x:String>
                        <x:String>June</x:String>
                        <x:String>July</x:String>
                        <x:String>August</x:String>
                        <x:String>September</x:String>
                        <x:String>October</x:String>
                        <x:String>November</x:String>
                        <x:String>December</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Number of months:"/>
                <Picker Title="Number of months" HorizontalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start">
                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>2</x:String>
                            <x:String>3</x:String>
                            <x:String>4</x:String>
                            <x:String>5</x:String>
                            <x:String>6</x:String>
                            <x:String>7</x:String>
                            <x:String>8</x:String>
                            <x:String>9</x:String>
                            <x:String>10</x:String>
                            <x:String>11</x:String>
                            <x:String>12</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                </Picker>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Number of publishers to visit each month:"/>
                <Picker Title="Number of publishers" HorizontalOptions="End">
                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>2</x:String>
                            <x:String>3</x:String>
                            <x:String>4</x:String>
                            <x:String>5</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                </Picker>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Starting publisher:"/>
            <Picker Title="Number of publishers">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Name 1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Name 2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Name 3</x:String>
                        <x:String>Name 4</x:String>
                        <x:String>Name 5</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
```

I am using Visual Studio for Mac with Xamarin 4.8. Want to use 5.x but I get exception running the software. The project output is MacOS. This is what I see at the moment:

[image]

I want to have the two inser (Number ...) `Picker` objects slightly wider and aligned to the right side. And then the label can take up the slack. At the moment it is staggered and the picker narrow.

I tried to use `HorizontalOptions` but failed.

Thanks for guidance.

Comment: Use HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" and set  WidthRequest

Comment: Depends on the width you want. Experiment with some values and see the result. 25 maybe ?

Comment: @Cfun I turned your comment into an answer. 75 seemed a good value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the advice in the comments I was able to adjust my XAML code like this:

```
<Picker Title="Number of publishers" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="75">
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>1</x:String>
            <x:String>2</x:String>
            <x:String>3</x:String>
            <x:String>4</x:String>
            <x:String>5</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

I needed to use:

- `HorizontalOptions`
- `WidthRequest`

[image]